# ftp csv file download with java

Tags: java, file, csv, ftp, download

I successfully download a csv file stored in ftp server using the code below.

```
URL url = new URL(ftpUrl); 
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
long filesize = conn.getContentLength();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = -1;

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    String str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    out.println(str);
}
```

The csv file has 1276KB filesize and about 20.000 rows. The problem is that the generated csv file has some lines either blank or with missing information. The damaged rows occur about every 100 records. I tried to fix by increasing the buffer size but damaged rows still exist. 
Any help is going to be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure! you have to tell how long is the string: except when the file size is a multiple of 4096, you will always get old items in `buffer`

You must use this syntax instead

```
String str = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, "utf-8");
```

Comment: I used the above suggestion and I still got the damaged rows (the file is a multiple of 4096). Then, I set the buffer size equal to the filesize and the problem was solved. I don't know if is an efficient solution.  Thanx for your answer!

Comment: It's surely not a good solution to put the entire file in memory. You had a problem with bytes filled from the previous iteration in the code you have in your question. I gave you a way to skip, the last bytes that are out of the bounds of the files (ex if readBytes gave you 6 bytes and the file ended, you would find your self with 4090 bytes coming from the previous read)...